# global:false for Ajax.BeginForm in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

In jquery ajax we use

```
$.ajax({
   url: "test.html",
   global: false
 });
```

In Ajax.BeginForm() is there a way of doing specifying global: false for not invoking global error.I just want to invoke localerror and then stop.

Comment: What global error is being invoked that you don't want invoked? The option in jQuery is to prevent global handlers like `$.ajaxStart` and `$.ajaxStop` from triggering.

Answer (score 0):

No, this option is not exposed with the `Ajax.*` helpers. But you could enable it globally for all requests using the [$.ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) method.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    global: false
});
```